PostGIS trigger to convert Curve to LineString
We have GIS data coming into PostGIS as ST_Curve and ST_MultiCurve when doing SELECT st_geometrytype(geom) even though it is meant to be ST_LineString data.  We're trying to figure the best way to convert this "on the fly" and the idea of PostGIS triggers came up.
We've used triggers for attribute data (text and numbers), but is there anything different when using spatial data?

No.  Triggers are triggers. Geometry is just an extension column type.

alter table your_table add column geom_as_linestring geometry generated always as (ST_CurveToLine(geom)) stored; this converts them on the fly, but keeps the original. Later you can disable the expression that generates it and drop the original column.

demo at db<>fiddle
alter table your_table 
  add column geom_as_linestring geometry 
  generated always as (ST_CurveToLine(geom)) stored;

This converts them on the fly, but keeps the original.
Once you're sure you're satisfied with the way you convert them (there are ST_CurveToLine() params you can tweak), you can disable the expression that generates it and drop the original column:
alter table your_table
  alter column geom_as_linestring drop expression
 ,drop column geom;
alter table your_table 
  rename column geom_as_linestring to geom;

This assumes you're on a PostgreSQL version that has more than a month of support left, meaning v13 or above. In v12, there's no drop expression. Before v12, this type of generated column isn't a thing.

Thanks, haven't worked a lot with generated columns but seems a great way to keep the original geom and have one that is application friendly, esp during development.
